# Induced voltage in loop around wire in home AC circuit

Tags: induction, faradays-law

I have an electric patio heater that has no indication of whether it's on or off. I want to wrap a loop of wire around its power cord, the goal being to induce a current that can power an LED to tell me if the heater is on.

The heater draws 15 amps at 240 volts. The cord is contained in a plastic conduit with diameter 1.5 inches. I am just a hobbyist when it comes to electronics. While Faraday's law seems simple to apply, I have no idea how to calculate the change in magnetic flux.

I need to know how many loops I need to make this work, and I'd love to learn how I could have solved this problem on my own.

Comment: How do you power it on? I'd place an illuminated switch instead of this voodoo.

Comment: The power cord has current going into the heater in one wire and current returning from the heater in another wire. The magnetic fields cancel out so any amount of wire looped around the power cord has zero output.

Comment: Easy method.   Have somebody stand by your electric meter (the thing the electric company uses to measure how much electricity you use...)    Flip the switch.  Does the meter start turning faster?   Then you just turned the heater on.   If it starts going slower, you turned it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no use to wrap wire around the power cord. The magnetic field of the wires has just that direction which induces nothing to your wire loop. Besides the fields of the cord wires cancel each other because there's 2 parallel wires with opposite current directions. In theory a long narrow loop where the wires are mostly in parallel with the cord wires could catch something but the caught power is probably 1000 times too weak to make a led to glow without a proper amplifier.

Do as suggested: Insert a switch with lamp. 15A current unfortunately excludes any common home appliance extension cords. I guess the heater has a permanent connection (=no plug). To stay in safe you need a proper electrician to insert the switch.

If you want indication of the state of the thermostat, too, you need a lamp which is inserted to the heater. It also is a modification that casual hobbyists should avoid to prevent fire and death.

NOT ASKED: If you can reach one of the powered cord wires without the other you could in theory build a current transformer. The wire is the primary of the transformer and the secondary feeds the led. 15A converted to 15mA for a led (or actually for a couple of leds because you need one for each current direction) needs 1000 turns in the secondary.

You will still need a proper electrician to help you, because current transformer can easily generate a high voltage if it's not loaded and threading the wire through the iron of the transformer may need to disconnect it temporarily. An open-close clamp removes the need to disconnect the wire, but it needs more space.

To learn something of current transformers see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_transformer

The next image is taken from the linked Wikipedia article:

[image]

Instead of the ammeter (=A) you should have 2 leds in parallel, but to opposite directions.

The iron core cannot be made of solid iron, it must fulfill general transformer iron core structural demands. Otherwise eddy currents spoil the functionality.